# Place two p tags side by side using flexbox

Tags: html, flexbox

I want to place two p tags side by side and to achieve this i am using the following method which works fine. But I was trying if I could get the same result using flexbox.

Normal method (works)-

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 50%;">
    <p style="float: left;">content1</p>
    <p style="float: right;">content2</p>
</div>
```

Flexbox -

```
<div class="d-flex" style="overflow: hidden; width: 50%;">
  <p style="justify-content: left;">content1</p>
  <p style="justify-content: right;">content2</p>
</div>
```

I want content 1 and content 2 to be at either end. Using justify-content as left/right or flex start/end is not working. How to implement this using flex ?

If there is another method also which is more direct and simpler , please let me know.

Thanks !

Comment: You should use `justify-content` on a `display: flex` element. In your case it's `.d-flex` `div`. Just add `justify-content: space-between` to it. If I got your desired result right

Comment: Could you please tell me the difference ? d-flex makes it a flex container. Why don't the properties work, then?

Comment: `justify-content` only works on `display: flex` elements, and you applied it to child elements. There is a good article about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to use `justify-content` on the wrapper-div. This way you can space your items equally. And since you only have two, one is on the left, the other is on the right side.

Another solution would be to use `margin-left: auto` on the second p-tag (see second example)

```css
.p-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.p-wrapper-two {
  display: flex;
}

.p-wrapper-two p:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2> Example one </h2>
<div class="p-wrapper">
  <p>content1</p>
  <p>content2</p>
</div>

<hr>

<h2> Example two </h2>

<div class="p-wrapper-two">
  <p>content1</p>
  <p>content2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <p style="justify-content: left;">content1</p>
  <p style="justify-content: right;">content2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **justify-content** property aligns the flexible container's items when the items do not use all available space on the main-axis (horizontally).

**justify-content** is to be placed on parent element, while **justify-self** can be placed on child element;

To make it achieve same result as the main one, set the value of *justify-content* to *space-between*.

You can read more about **justify-content** [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)